# Making living room scenes with rugs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I want to showcase my rugs for customers on my website and looking for a tool to create a scene like this:

[image]

I can't do photography in real room or studio and I was told that there might be an app to make these kinds of decorations.

Comment: Do you have the actual photos of your rugs? Or you do not have any photo.

Comment: @Rafael I do have rugs photo but in top view and not in perspective view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it can be done in Photoshop.

Find a nice image on a stock photography site of a room with tables and chairs, preferably on a plain wooden floor - obviously one without a rug! Pay for a licence to use the image so you won't be sued.

Something like this perhaps

[image]

Then with the Pen Tool, make a vector clipping mask around the table and chair legs. Apply the vector mask to a copy of the image layer.

Paste an image of a rug under the masked layer, turn it into a Smart Object. Use `Edit` > `Transform` > `Distort` and move the corners to match the perspective of the room.

Tah dah!

[image: Example edit]

If you double click the Smart Object to edit it, you can just paste in another rug, resize it as required, quit and save the Smart Object, and you'll have a new carpet on the floor.

[image: Editing the Smart Object]

And here's the result when you save and close the Smart Object - a new rug!

[image: Example of another carpet on the floor]

Comment: One may wish to add a contact shadow and specular layer

Comment: @joojaa Well yes, if you want added realism, that would be a great idea.